# Handling application data as a frontend developer

Tags: database, reactjs, firebase, local-storage, frontend

So I'm working on building my first application in React. I really don't know much about databases, data models, schema, etc. Is it bad practice to just store my data in the browser as I develop then worry about hooking my app up to something like firebase later?

For example, below I store some user data in an object called user and just go from there. As long as I have some way of accessing it later. Keeping in mind I'm in the beginning stages of frontend development is this bad practice?

Thanks!

```
var SignUpForm = React.createClass({
    getUserInfo : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var user = {
            name : this.refs.name.value,
            userName : this.refs.userName.value,
            email : this.refs.email.value,
            password : this.refs.password.value
        }

        console.log(user)
        this.refs.signUpForm.reset();
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.getUserInfo} ref="signUpForm">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>First and Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="userName" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" ref="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" ref="password" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
            </form> 
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Totally reasonable while in the prototyping phase. Look into `localStorage` which would allow you to keep things around even after a browser refresh: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: No issues with that at all. I would just spend a little more time to get your data in a well organized format. So that way when you go to hook it up to firebase later on, you don't need to rework any of your data. You can just simply save the objects you've already created

Comment: This is okay for prototyping purposes or in the case of of developing projects that may not continue, then yes just locally store the data for a quick demo.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Much appreciated.